# Category dropdown only works on contact's page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, osclass

I have a dropdown menu with various categories on my website however the dropdown only works on my contact page. I have added a link with my code below

```
<?php
/*
* Osclass – software for creating and publishing online classified
* advertising platforms
*
* Copyright (C) 2014 OSCLASS
*
* This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
* the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
* WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
* GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public
* License along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="<?php echo str_replace('_', '-', osc_current_user_locale()); ?>">
<head>
<?php osc_current_web_theme_path('common/head.php') ; ?>
</head>
<body <?php bender_black_body_class(); ?>>



<div class="uptop">

<?php if( osc_users_enabled() || ( !osc_users_enabled() && !osc_reg_user_post() )) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo osc_item_post_url_in_category(); ?>"><?php _e("Publish your ad for free", 'bender_black');?></a>

<?php } ?>

</div>



<div id="header">

<!-- header ad 728x60-->
<div class="ads_header">
<?php echo osc_get_preference('header-728x90', 'bender_black'); ?> <!-- THIS WAS AN ADs PLACED AT THE TOP OF LOGO -->
<!-- /header ad 728x60-->
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="logo">
<?php echo logo_header(); ?>
<span id="description"><?php echo osc_page_description(); ?></span>
</div>
<ul class="nav">
<?php /* if( osc_is_static_page() || osc_is_contact_page() ){ COMMENTING THIS OUT SO THAT SEARCH & CATEGORY SHOWS ON ALL PAGES */ ?>
<li class="search"><a class="ico-search icons" data-bclass-toggle="display-search"></a></li>
<li class="cat"><a class="ico-menu icons" data-bclass-toggle="display-cat"></a></li>
<?php /*} */ ?>
<?php if( osc_users_enabled() ) { ?>
<?php if( osc_is_web_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<li class="first logged">
<span><?php echo sprintf(__('Hi %s', 'bender_black'), osc_logged_user_name() . '!'); ?> &middot;</span>
<strong><a href="<?php echo osc_user_dashboard_url[); ?>"><?php _e('My account', 'bender_black'); ?></a></strong> &middot;
<a href="<?php echo osc_user_logout_u rl(); ?>"><?php _e('Logout', 'bender_black'); ?></a>
</li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><a id="login_open" href="<?php echo osc_user_login_u rl(); ?>"><?php _e('Login', 'bender_black') ; ?></a></li>
<?php if(osc_user_registration_enabled()) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo osc_register_account_u rl() ; ?>"><?php _e('Register for a free account', 'bender_black'); ?></a></li>
<?php }; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php if( osc_users_enabled() || ( !osc_users_enabled() && !osc_reg_user_post() )) { ?>
<li class="publish"><a href="<?php echo osc_item_post_url_in_category() ; ?>"><?php _e("Publish your ad for free", 'bender_black');?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>

<?php /* if( osc_is_home_page() || osc_is_static_page() || osc_is_contact_page() ) { */ ?>
<?php if( 1 == 1 ) { ?>
<form action="<?php echo osc_base_u rl(true); ?>" method="get" class="search nocsrf" <?php /* onsubmit="javascript:return doSearch();"*/ ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="search"/>
<div class="main-search">
<div class="cell">
<input type="text" name="sPattern" id="query" class="input-text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo osc_esc_html(__(osc_get_preference('keyword_placeholder', 'bender_black'), 'bender_black')); ?>" />
</div>
<?php if ( osc_count_categories() ) { ?>
<div class="cell selector">
<?php osc_categories_select('sCategory', null, __('Select a category', 'bender_black')) ; ?>
</div>
<div class="cell reset-padding">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="cell">
<?php } ?>
<button class="ui-button ui-button-big js-submit"><?php _e("Search", 'bender_black'];?></button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="message-seach"></div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<?php osc_show_widgets('header'); ?>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-flash">

<nav id="nav-main">
<ul>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=4"><?php _e("Rooms","bender_black");?></a> </li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=6"><?php _e("Electronics","bender_black");?></a></li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=2"><?php _e("Vehicles","bender_black");?></a></li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=3"><?php _e("Books","bender_black");?></a></li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=8"><?php _e("Clothes","bender_black");?></a></li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=5"><?php _e("Services","bender_black");?></a></li>
<li> <a href="index.php?page=search&sCategory=1"><?php _e("General","bender_black");?></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="nav-trigger">
<span><?php _e("Categories","bender_black");?></span>
</div>
<nav id="nav-mobile"></nav>

<?php echo osc_get_preference('homepage-728x90', 'bender_black'); ?> <!---- MOVED THIS ADs SECTION FROM LINE 31 TO HERE ----->


<?php
$breadcrumb = osc_breadcrumb('&raquo;', false, get_breadcrumb_lang());
if( $breadcrumb !== '') { ?>
<div class="breadcrumb">
<?php echo $breadcrumb; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php osc_show_flash_message(); ?>
</div>
<?php osc_run_hook('before-content'); ?>
<div class="wrapper" id="content">
<?php osc_run_hook('before-main'); ?>
<div id="main">
<!-- this line lists all categories on main page <?php osc_run_hook('inside-main'); ?> --->
```

I believe the line

```
<li class="cat"><a class="ico-menu icons" data-bclass-toggle="display-cat"></a></li>
<?php /*} 
      */ 
?>
```

controls the dropdown however I don't understand why it would work on 1 page but not the others?

see how the dropdown should look on all pages

[image]

EDIT: 
[Here is the image of the javascript error found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnj7S.jpg)

Comment: It can be due to a conflict with other JavaScript on page. Open the error console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Firefox on Linux and Windows) or Developer tools (F12 → Console) and check if any JavaScript errors are displayed there.

Comment: I think you're onto something. I got the following error after following your suggestion. <br/> Error: missing required parameters: sitekey <br/> I'll edit the original post to show an image of the error message

Comment: Anybody around?

Comment: The error says your Recaptcha is not configured correctly, the site key is not properly set. I don’t know how to configure Recaptcha, I’ve never used it. You might want to ask another question about it. (However, before you ask another question, make sure this error doesn’t appear on the contact page. If it does, it means this is NOT the problem.)

Comment: The error also appears on the contact page so it seems the issue isn't with Recaptcha.